# No sound in bluetooth headset when switching user

Tags: linux, bluetooth, kde, manjaro, wireless-headset

I'm using Manjaro KDE, and I've got 2 registered users (let's say UserA and UserB). My bluetooth headset (Bose QC45) is correctly paired so that if I boot my computer, start a session, and switch my headset on, I can hear everything correctly (music, videogames, etc).

However, when I'm on UserA with my headset on, and I switch to UserB without rebooting and without closing session, then I get absolutely no sound in the UserB session, despite my headset being shown as connected in the KDE UI. Even if I turn my headset off and on so that it reconnects, I still have no sound. But if I switch back to UserA, the sound comes back. I've also tried turning my headset off before switching user and turning it back on after, but it still doesn't work.

It seems whenever my headset is connected while on a user session, then I can't use it at all on any other user session unless I reboot my computer.

Is this normal behaviour? Is there a parameter that I need to change? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behaviour because the Bluetooth accessory is still in use by UserA when you switched to UserB.

Your solution would be to disconnect the bluetooth device for UserA before switching profile to UserB. Or signing out of UserA instead of switching should also work.

You could try disabling fast user switching within local group policy. This will make sure users are signed out when the machine tries to switch to another user profile.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer! I was hoping precisely not to have to sign out when switching to another user, but I guess I'll have to make do.